# C++ - Simple binary to ASCII binary program

Tags: c++, binary, console

Ok, this question is very specific and i'll be brief.
I'm trying to convert a simple binary of 5 digits into decimal and then into a ASCII decimal number;
But somehow my input is:

> Type a binary number: 10110
>
> Finished? (y/n): n
>
> Finished? (y/n): n

It was supposed to be asking finished only after asking for another binary number, then showing a sentence in a char array when I typed y. What happenned? I just cant really understand what happenned...

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "binconverts.h"

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    int numBin;
    char acabou;
    bool breakLoop = false;
    int numer = 0;
    cout << "Digite um numero binario: ";
    cin >> numBin;
    for (int a = 0; a < 54; a++){
        if (breakLoop == true) break;
        binconv.text[a] = binconv.convBin(numBin);
        numer++;
        cout << "Acabou? (s/n): ";
        cin >> acabou;
        switch (acabou){
        case 'S':
            breakLoop == true;
            break;
        case 's':
            breakLoop == true;
            break;
        case 'n':
            breakLoop == false;
            break;
        case 'N':
            breakLoop == false;
            break;
        default:
            breakLoop == false;
            break;}
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < numer; b++){
        cout << binconv.text[b];
    }
}
```

---

```
//binconverts.h
#pragma once
#include "rick_math.h"

class BINCONV{
public:
    int convBin(int);
    int setText();
    char text[54];
}binconv;

BINCONV::convBin(int n){
    int decimal(0), i(0), rem;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        rem = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        decimal += rem * maths.poten(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal + 63;}
```

Comment: in your program you are using s/n, but the output is using y/n. Please correct to the proper way. Thx.

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't show you that message 54 times since `breakLoop == false;` and the other expressions like this in your switch block are not an assignment but a comparison. I think you need `breakLoop = false` and so on...

Comment: BTW, using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` will reduce the `switch` cases by 50%.  Apply a function to convert the character to uppercase or lower case before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

This should improve the format and funktionality of your code

```
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    int numBin;
    char acabou;
    bool breakLoop = false;
    int numer = 0;
    cout << "Digite um numero binario: ";
    cin >> numBin;
    cout << "Acabou? (s/n): ";
    for (int a = 0; a < 54; a++){
        if (breakLoop == true) break;
        binconv.text[a] = binconv.convBin(numBin);
        numer++;
        cin >> acabou;
        if (acabou="s" || acabou="S"){
            breakLoop = true;
        }else {
            breakLoop = false;
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < numer; b++){
            cout << binconv.text[b];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You realize you are using a loop inside another loop, so the `if (breakLoop == true) break;` only works for the inner loop and the message will be shown 54 times regardless of what the user choose.

Comment: now it should work. I only forgot to put `cout << "Acabou? (s/n): ";` out of the  for-loop

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer `for` loop?

Comment: You can improve funktionality further by using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` to convert the character variable before the `if` statement.